# Using Cocos2D vs UIKit to create an app which incorporates puzzle games

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I searched SO a bit but was not able to find an answer.  I am going to be working on an app which incorporates different type of games in it.  I am not sure if i should dive in to learn cocos2d or just keep learning UIKit.  The games are going to be 2D puzzle like games.  In the game a user will need to move pieces around, color them in and they will have some kind of animation when the level is finished, for example stars flying or fireworks. Can this be done with UIKit alone? Are there specific books/tutorials on UIKit on how to create such puzzle games?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends only on your design and creative features, if there will be lots of animation tricks You should try to use cocos2D (for it has some useful components for memory regulations), if the engine is pretty simple  - UIKit will be enough for your game.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  The app will be mostly static images and some animation on top of them.  The most of the animation tricks would be some fireworks or stars flying around from a point.

Comment: Nothing special for cocos, however for fireworks you can use CCParticleSystem in cocos2d [CCParticleSystem tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5426).